# Spring MVC receiving entity from ajax as List<Issues> pagination

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have made spring `@RequestMapping` which accepts POST request with JSON data.
I am getting deserialized List by sending ajax through my thymeleaf. (most
of logic is javascript rest API, which I am consuming and passing further to Spring)
I need make some sort of pagination with spring I have found some guide
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-pagination, but need to access my data which I am sending to `RequestMapping` controller.
**Can I in some way autowire this instance without storing it into data layer?
I have access to List from controller.**
I expect that in my @Service class I access these data from spring controller,
and implement pagination. I have also splited first 10 issues rest, which I am sending
through aformentioned @RequestMapping and then another rest for all other issues `/receiveNextIssues` (send to Spring by POST ajax), where I want implement pagination in Java and then in jquery after onclick call another rest for chosen page like `/listIssues?page=5` (access from html)

Comment: What you want to achieve is not clear in description. Can you please paste minimal code and what is expected output, and what challenge you are facing currently.

Comment: @PageableDefault(sort = { "name",}, value = 50) Pageable pageable. Have you tried pagableDefault annotation. page, size objects can be get from ajax request and you can use spring data repository to get pageable object. That is all I can say from your question.

Comment: How can I access firstTen    @RequestMapping(value = "/receiveFirstTenIssues", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String receiveFirstTenIssues(@RequestBody List<Issue> firstTen, 
elsewhere in spring I want make some design, as in example BookService nedd IssueService where pagination will happen not in my rest